# how to create an id to be shown in the text box based on selected dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql-server

i would like to create an id generator based on their department selected from the dropdownlist. lets say my ddl has 3 departments (A,B,C) and when generating an id it will be A20181001 and then A20181002 upon submission but when i pick B from the ddl after sending A20181001 to the database, it will be B20181001.

so far i have created the code for the increment for the id without the departments. here is the code i did so far. (I used the date for today so the 20181001 is just an example):

```
void getMRF_No()
        {
            string year = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            int mrf = 0;
            int i;
            string a;
            //string x = Request.QueryString["BUnit"];
            string mrfNo = "";
            database db = new database();
            string conn = dbe.BU();
            SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand cmd = connUser.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataReader sdr = null;

            string query = "SELECT TOP 1 MRF_NO FROM incMRF ORDER BY MRF_NO DESC";


            connUser.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                mrfNo = sdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();


            }

            if (mrfNo == "")
            {
                mrfNo = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + 00;

            }
            mrf += 0;
            i = Convert.ToInt32(mrfNo) + 1;

            a = i.ToString();



            txtMRFNo.Text = a;



            connUser.Close();

        }
```

any help to improve this code will be helpful. thank you :)

EDIT:
here is the dropdown list code:

```
void SelectBU()
        {
            string database = dbe.BU ();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(database))
            {
                con.Open();

                string query = "select BUnit from BusinessUnit";
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds, "BUnit");
                    ddlBu.DataSource = ds;
                    ddlBu.DataTextField = "BUnit";
                    ddlBu.DataValueField = "BUnit";
                    ddlBu.DataBind();

                    selectOption(ddlBu, "Select Dept");
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

EDIT2: I will state what im searching for here incase some doesnt know or understand. What i want is upon selecting a department from a dropdownlist, for example i picked A. the textbox show show A2018102201. if i select B it should show B2018102201 and if its C then c2018102201. and it will change its number once i submit it to a database and a new form loads. So if A2018102201 is already in the database, then the text shown in the text box will be A2018102202. BUT if i select B then the textbox will show B2018102201 since it does not exist in the database yet.

Comment: This code wil return the same number every time you call it. There is no logic to increment the value on the database

Comment: i mean upon submiting to the database it will increase from 2018102101 to 2018102102

Comment: You might consider creating a database `SEQUENCE` for each department so you can get the next value and tack it onto the rest of the generated id.

Answer (score -1):

First you should get **max ID**, then increase the numeric part of your Id, and If this is a multi-user application, you have to `lock` your table, because it might create many ID `duplication`, Therefore I'm not recommend to create ID like this on c#, it is better to create a `Sequence` on SQL server. but I wrote this sample for you, just call it with proper value.

```
static string getMRF_No(string prefixCharFromDropDownList)
{
    string year = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    string mrfNo = "";

    SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection("Server=130.185.76.162;Database=StackOverflow;UID=sa;PWD=$1@mssqlICW;connect timeout=10000");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        $"SELECT MAX(MRF_NO) as MaxID FROM incMRF where MRF_NO like '{prefixCharFromDropDownList}%'"
        ,connUser
        );
    connUser.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        mrfNo = sdr["MaxID"].ToString();
    }
    if (mrfNo == "")
    {
        mrfNo = prefixCharFromDropDownList +  year + "000";
    }
    else
    {
        mrfNo = prefixCharFromDropDownList +  (long.Parse(mrfNo.Substring(1)) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(2);
    }

    sdr.Close();
    cmd = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO incMRF (MRF_NO) values ('{mrfNo}')",connUser);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connUser.Close();
    //txtMRFNo.Text = prefixCharFromDropDownList + i.ToString();
    return mrfNo;

}
```

I call this method on a console application as test.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // send dropdown (selected char) as prefix to method
    var newAId = getMRF_No("A");
    var newAnotherAId = getMRF_No("A");
    var newBId = getMRF_No("B");
    var newAnotherAId2 = getMRF_No("A");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: @allos let me know, if you still have problem.

Comment: i have a question is it possible to show it in the textbox too?? Like example  txtMRF_No.text will show the id only upon selecting the department.

Comment: Of course you can un-comment  that life which realted to txtMRFNo and show it into text box,but don't forget to remove  (static) before method signature, and send proper value to method.

Comment: I test this code and if this is worked for you, accept my answer, because someone vote-down my answer, before test it :)))

Comment: I have a problem. It seems even when i change dropdownlist, it does not seem to be updating the text box. when i select B it still stays at A.

Comment: My dropdownlist is in the question now

Comment: I left my desk, I will update my answer next few hours ;)